# Microsoft mouse side buttons (on the left and right) don't work in win7-64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, mouse, intellimouse

Microsoft mouse side buttons (on the left and right) don't work in win7-64

I have installed Intellipoint and mapped the buttons to specific actions.
They don't work in most applications and I'm thinking it may have something to do with WoW64.

Can anyone confirm they are experiencing similar issues and if they fixed it, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed for my Notebook Optical Mouse 3000 on Win7-64 and it works.

I assume you installed the Intellipoint 7 64-bit version from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=MK)?

Also check that the mouse/pointer properties in the control panel.